# Proving the inverse operator theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $A:X\to Y$ by a bijective bounded linear operator. Let $\delta > 0$ be a constant such that $B_\delta(0;Y) \subset A(B_1(0))$. Then we have that
$$
\inf_{\substack{x\in X\\ Ax = y}} ||x||_X \le \delta^{-1}||y||_Y, \quad \text{for all} \ y \in Y.
$$
I want to show that the inverse operator $A^{-1}:Y\to X$ is bounded by showing that $||A^{-1}|| \le \delta^{-1}$.

Here is what I have done:
$$
\begin{align}
||A^{-1}|| = \sup_{||y||=1}||A^{-1}y||_X \\
= \sup_{{\substack{x\in X\\ Ax = y\\||y||=1}}}||x||_X \\
\end{align}
$$
But I have a $\sup$ in this expression instead of an $\inf$ so I can't use the inequality above to finish the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only use $B_\delta(0;Y) \subset A(B_1(0))$:

to this end take $y \in Y$ with $y \ne 0$. Then $z:=\frac{\delta}{||y||_Y}y \in B_\delta(0;Y) \subset A(B_1(0))$. Hence there is $x \in X$ with $||x||_X \le 1$ and $z=Ax$. It follows:

$A^{-1}y=\frac{||y||_Y}{\delta}x$, hence

$$||A^{-1}y||_X \le \frac{||y||_Y}{\delta}.$$

This gives

$$||A^{-1}|| \le \delta^{-1}.$$

Comment: That's great thanks! Is it also possible to obtain it with the method I was using or had I run into a 100% dead end?

Comment: Linking Related Question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346508/theorem-5-10-in-rudins-real-complex-analysis